# Syncing network folder with Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am not a developer but was looking into google drive for my business. I asked if they could sync a folder on a networked extrnal harddrive. I was instructed to write an app. I run a business I am not a developer. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like [gdrive_sync](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gdrive_sync/0.5)

You don't have to write any code but you will need to install python, download this program, and do some typing in a command line window.

After you download and install python... download gdrive_sync and extract it to a directory with 7zip.  Then open a command line and go to the directory you extracted to and type

```
setup.py install
```

to install the program.  Then follow the instructions under the "Usage" section of the link above to synchronize your drives with google drive.  It's a powerful and free way to use google drive if you are willing to spend a bit of time on it.